# Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors

Tags: oracle, plsql

Please check my package and procedures.

My package:

```
create or replace package transaction1 as
    procedure enter_transaction(acc number, kind varchar2, amount number);
    procedure apply_transaction;
end;
/
```

This is my body:

```
create or replace package body transaction1 as
    procedure enter_transaction(acc in number, kind in varchar2, amount in number) 
    is

    begin

    end;

    procedure apply_transaction
    is

    begin

    end;    
end;
/
```

What is the warning? Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you see a warning: `Errors: check compiler log`

then run `show errors` command and you will see the error log :

```
7/5            PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge

14/5           PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
```

In case of your package body Oracle complains because `BEGIN END` blocks don't contain any commands.
In Oracle the BEGIN-END block must contain at least one command. Could be NULL, if you don't want to run anything (and don't forget to place a semicolon after NULL command):

```
PROCEDURE ......
IS
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
```